# How to give hide/show feature to certain components when it is mapped in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mapping

I am getting certain response from api:

```
[
    {   
        "name": "cds",
        "user_id": "1b625caf-9bea-4846-bdec-0cbcd76149cf"
    },
    {   
        "name": "asd",
        "user_id": "1b625caf-9bea-4846-bdec-0cbcd76149cf"
    },
    {
        "name": "qee",
        "user_id": "1b625caf-9bea-4846-bdec-0cbcd76149cf"
    },
    {
        "name": "cbb",
        "user_id": "1b625caf-9bea-4846-bdec-0cbcd76149cf"
    },
    {
        "name": "rty",
        "user_id": "1b625caf-9bea-4846-bdec-0cbcd76149cf"
    },
]
```

And I am using a component to show the details of this api:

```
<TouchableOpacity>
    <Text>Toggle</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

{upcoming.map((item: any, key: any) => (
    <>
        <UpComingComponent
            name={item.name}
        />
    </>
))}
```

I am able to map the component successfully, But I need to have a feature, where initially user can see only two mapped `UpComingComponent`, and when user clicks on `toggle`, user should see all the mapped `UpComingComponent`, and when he again clicks on `toggle`, user show again only see two `UpComingComponent`.

I know how to have hide/show a component, but my problem is I have show two components initially, then `toggle`, show all the components, and again `toggle`, show only two components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and combine it with a state variable for `toggle`:

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setToggle(t => !t)}>
    <Text>Toggle</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

{toggle ? upcoming.map((item: any, key: any) => (
    <>
        <UpComingComponent
            name={item.name}
        />
    </>
)) : upcoming.slice(0,2).map() => ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the list for the first two items based on their index.

```
upcoming
.filter((item, index) => (!showAll ? index < 2 : true))
.map((item) => (
  <>
    <UpComingComponent name={item.name} />
  </>
));
```